# Transferring file from One servlet to another servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I have Java application with two servlets. The first servlet will upload the file. I want to send the file from the first servlet to second servlet.

Uploading file:

```
public void post(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // set location for saving uploaded file
        UploadBean upb = new UploadBean();
        /*
         * Path path = Paths.get(UPLOAD_DIR).toAbsolutePath();
         * System.out.println(path); String strPath = path.toString();
         */
        upb.setFolderstore(UPLOAD_DIR);
        upb.setFilesizelimit(1073741824);
        upb.setOverwrite(true);

        // 1024 * 1024 * 100
        // 1073741824
        // 1048576

        MultipartFormDataRequest nreq = new MultipartFormDataRequest(
                request);
        // completed file uploading

        upb.store(nreq);
        Hashtable<?, ?> ht = nreq.getFiles();// gives the uploaded file
        Enumeration<?> e = ht.elements();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            upfile = (UploadFile) e.nextElement();
            uploadFilePath = UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator;
            File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
            if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
                fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
            }
            file = UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator + upfile.getFileName();
            filePath = new File(file).getAbsolutePath();
            fileName = upfile.getFileName()
                    .substring(0, upfile.getFileName().indexOf("."))
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", "").trim().concat("_")
                    .concat("data");
        }
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("./vdr.h‌​tml");
        request.setAttribute("filePath", filePath);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Analysis:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("text/html");

    double base_x = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n1"));
    double base_y = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n2"));
    double m0 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n3"));
    double a = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n4"));
    double b = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n5"));
    double k1 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n6"));
    double k2 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n7"));
    double k3 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n8"));
    double k4 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n9"));
    double k5 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n10"));
    double k6 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n11"));
    double k7 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n12"));
    double k8 = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n13"));
    double Lbp = Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("n14"));

    double ido00 = base_x * PI / 180.0;

    double keido00 = base_y * PI / 180.0;

    double s0 = k1 * ido00 + k2 * Math.sin(2.0 * ido00) + k3
            * Math.sin(4.0 * ido00) + k4 * Math.sin(6.0 * ido00) + k5
            * Math.sin(8.0 * ido00) + k6 * Math.sin(10.0 * ido00) + k7
            * Math.sin(12.0 * ido00) + k8 * Math.sin(14.0 * ido00);
    double f = 1.0 / 299.152813;
    double e2 = (Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2)) / Math.pow(a, 2);

    pw.println("VDR Analysis " + ido00 + "  " + keido00 + "  " + s0 + "  "
            + f + "  " + e2);
    pw.close();

    //get the uploaded file

}
```

index.html:

```
<body style="background-color: #d6e6f6;">
<form action="ts2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
                  .....................................
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```

vdr.html:

```
<body style="background-color: #d6e6f6;">
<form name="myForm" action="ts2" method="post"
    onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

web.xml:

```
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ts1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imu.reqdis.AisNmeaFileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ts2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.imu.reqdis.VDRAnalysis</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ts1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/ser1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ts2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ser2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet1 :

[image: File Uploading]

Servlet2:

[image: Calculate the input values using the uploaded file]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: A question would be why do you want to use 2 servlets for file processing? Why not just a single servlet?

Comment: yeah or a servlet to take the file upload and a Plain Old Java Object class to process the file which you use from the Servlet.

Comment: @SaifAsif The first servlet for file upload, and second servlet i have to take input values to make calculations from the uploaded file.

Comment: @Gimby The first servlet for file upload, and second servlet i have to take input values to make calculations from the uploaded file.

Comment: Aha, so there is a view in between those two servlet invocations. I'd stick the file on disc somewhere then.

Comment: @Gimby there are only two views.when i perform action on the upload button in servlet1(serv1.html) it should store the file to disc and forward the file to servlet2(ser2.html)

Comment: No; it should forward the unique filename. The file is on disc, there it is safe until you need it again. You don't need to keep the file around in memory until you need to process it again.

Comment: @Gimby ok can you give a sample code for doing it.

Comment: I can, but I'm not going to because that would be wasted time on my part. Google 'java servlet forward data' and find the existing example code. Or perhaps just read a book on servlets.

Comment: @Gimby is this right? which i have written above in my code request.setAttribute("filePath",filePath);request.getRequestDispatcher("./srv2.html").forward(request, response);

Comment: Why ask me when you can just try and see if it works?

Comment: @Gimby I have tried, it is not working, getting null pointer exception

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Time to update your post in stead of dragging out this conversation in the comments.